# How to insert mathmatics symbols, physics forces symbols etc to a photo to show parameters of a uav robotic system? Could someone point me a tutorial?

Tags: photo-editing

How are you?

I'm a grad student and I need to do a mathmatical and physical model a quadcopter robotic system . I've found a web site with a picture that looks like a lot to what I have to do: I have to take a picture of the robotic system i've built (it's not that in the picture but is similar) and draw and show all the forces and measures that this picure have.

What program can I use to do all these things? Could someone point me some tutorial?

PS: I'm citing the article in my research ;)
https://charlestytler.com/quadcopter-equations-motion/

[image]

Comment: Practically **any** image editor will allow one to draw shapes, arrows, create text, etc. There's nothing overly complex about that image.

Comment: Thanks, Scott! I also found this link that will help me: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/401/what-software-programs-are-used-to-draw-physics-diagrams-and-what-are-their-rel

Comment: I don't have any real experience with many things listed in that question, but [free: Inkscape, Gimp] or [paid: Illustrator, Photoshop].. are all winners.